# algorithm in STL to sweep 2 ranges and call a function

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

Is there a algorithm in STL that will sweep two (equally sized) ranges and call a function for each pair of entries?

`std::equal()` and `std::transform()` seem to follow this notion, but they are not that expressive when the intention is to, say, calculate the sum of difference squares of two vectors:

```
vector<double> a = { 1.1, 1.0, 5.5 };
vector<double> b = { 1.4, 1.1, 5.3 };

// intended action
double sum_of_squared_diffs ( vector<double> a, vector<double> b ) {

   double sum =0;
   for (size_t i=0; i<a.size(); i++) {    // a.size() == b.size()
       sum += std::pow(a[i] - b[i], 2.0);
   }
   return sum;
}

// expressed with std::equal :(
double sum = 0;
std::equal(a.begin(), a.end(), 
           b.begin(), b.end(), [&sum](double a, double b) {
   sum += std::pow(a-b, 2.0);
   return false;
});
```

- is there a more suitable algorithm in STL to express the intention?
- should I write my own?
- or are there better ways of writing this, preferably for C++11/14 ?

Comment: range-v3 has `zip_view`, and then you can apply `reduce`/`accumulate`.

Comment: You should write your own one. Algorithm STL cannot offer all needs to specific UCs. Also it's not much difficult to implement

Comment: There is [std::transform_reduce](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform_reduce) in C++17

Comment: `std::inner_product(a.begin(),a.end(),b.begin(),0.,std::plus<>(), [](double a, double b){ return std::pow(a-b,2); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard library has both [`inner_product`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product) and [`transform_reduce`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform_reduce) that'll do this for you. The latter is C++17.

```
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> a = { 1.1, 1.0, 5.5 };
    std::vector<double> b = { 1.4, 1.1, 5.3 };

    auto func = [](double a, double b)
        {
        return std::pow(a - b, 2);
        };

    double val1 = std::transform_reduce(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), 0.0, std::plus<>(), func);
    double val2 = std::inner_product(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), 0.0, std::plus<>(), func);

    std::cout << val1 << "\n" << val2 << "\n";
}
```

Comment: `inner_product` and `transform_reduce` seem very specific to the example (which *sums* the results of binary operations. I think we lack a more general function, such as `std::foreach(first1, last1, first2, last2, binary_op)`.

Comment: @GrimFandango it's only `+` because of the `std::plus` argument. Where do the results of your `binary_op` go?

Comment: @Caleth, yes, I did not notice that -- thank you!